# FunctionCompile examples for Computer Vision

Tags: image-processing, image, compile, function-compile

I'm looking for some good examples of FunctionCompile applied to image processing code since there doesn't seem to be anything on this in the documentation. So here's a first attempt at a hello world fails:

```
cf = Function[Typed[img, TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["UnsignedInteger8", 3]], Map[255-#&, img, {3}]];
img = ImageData[ExampleData[{"AerialImage","Earth"}], "Byte"]
Image[cf[img], "Byte"]
FunctionCompileExportString[cf, "Assembler", TargetSystem -> "WebAssembly"]
```

[image]

*Can someone knowledgeable in the new compiler please speak to this use case?*

A good answer here would also touch on the following:

- Where and when (if at all) FunctionCompiling speeds up image related computations?
- What can be done for compiling image related code for export to WASM?
- Getting TypeSpecifiers right is tricky, are there any tip/tools/tricks to check if a spec correctly matches data?

---

#### Update

I've constructed some working image processing examples using `FunctionCompile`, however, as yet there seem to be no tangible benefits or advantages in using the new compiler :/

1. FunctionCompile does not result in faster code
2. FunctionCompiling basic image operations often results in cryptic exceptions
3. My hope was that we could compile top-level computer vision code to WebAssembly, but this almost always fails

Now for examples demonstrating these three issues:

**1. Basic pixel operations are slower**

Compare the speed of a compiled pixelwise transform and its `ImageApply` counterpart:

```
fc1 = FunctionCompile[
        Function[{Typed[img, "PackedArray"["MachineInteger", 3]]},
            Module[{sf},
                sf = Function[{list},
                    Module[{res = list, d = Dimensions @ list},
                        Do[res[[y, x]] = Round[res[[y, x]]^.8 * {2, 0, 1}], {y, d[[1]]},
                             {x, d[[2]]}]; res
                    ]
                ]; sf[img]
            ]
        ],
        CompilerOptions -> {"InvocationMode" -> "Standalone", "LLVMOptimization" -> "ClangOptimization"[3], "AbortHandling" -> False}
    ]
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage","Volubilis"}];
AbsoluteTiming@Image[fc1[Normal@Image`InternalImageData[img]], "Byte"]
AbsoluteTiming@Image[ImageApply[((#*255)^.8*{2,0,1})/255&, Image[img,"Byte"]],"Byte"]
```

[image]

**2. Very often correct code doesn't compile**

Take a basic pixel sorting example, it seems to work fine:

```
fc2 = FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[img, "PackedArray"["MachineInteger",
     3]]}, Module[{sf}, sf = Function[{list}, Module[{res = list, d = Dimensions
     @ list, h}, Do[If[RandomReal[] > .2, h = RandomInteger[{1, d[[1]]}];
     res[[ ;; h, x]] = Sort[(res[[ ;; h, x]])]; x++; Continue[]]; , {x, d[[
    2]]}]; res]]; sf[img]]]]
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage","Tree"}];
AbsoluteTiming@Image[fc2[Normal@Image`InternalImageData[img]], "Byte"]
```

[image]

But this example breaks if you make tiny tweaks. Try replacing `Sort` with `ReverseSort`:

[image]

Try replacing the spans `;;h` with `h;;` and it dies:

[image]

**3. FunctionCompiling to WASM object code fails**

I was very enthused after seeing this [featured example](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/code-compilation/create-machine-code-for-exotic-architectures.html?product=mathematica), but it doesn't seem work on either of the above two CompiledCodeFunction's:

```
FunctionCompileExportString[fc1, "Assembler", TargetSystem -> "WebAssembly"]
```

[image]

```
FunctionCompileExportString[fc2, "Assembler", TargetSystem -> "WebAssembly"]
```

[image]

Hopefully I'm just doing something wrong here, because I would really like to use the new compiler to speed-up and export computer vision related code.

Comment: It must be a bug that `Map` with a level spec doesn't work, as `Function[Typed[im, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["MachineInteger", 1]],
   Map[255 - # &, im]];` works fine, but changing 1 to 2 or 3 and adding {2} or {3} in the `Map` breaks it.

Comment: @flinty Try maybe flattening everything?

Comment: Wow, I really thought at least one person might know how to do this...

Comment: @flinty I did some digging, see my edits

Comment: I don't find the performance difference that surprising. The compiled code isn't going to be as good as `ImageApply` which has been finely tuned.

Comment: @flinty Yes I agree, but just wanted to put it up for comparison.

Comment: @flinty however, there are some non-image examples where FunctionCompile version of a builtin is shown to be faster...